# Custom header with ExpanderView from Toolkit for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

I am using ExpanderView from Toolkit for Windows Phone. What I add is line below each Header. What I can't do is stretch line for Headers which are Expandable.

```
<toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="ev" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,8" 
                                        Header="{Binding}"
                                        NonExpandableHeader="{Binding}"
                                        Expander="{Binding}"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                        IsNonExpandable="{Binding HasSingleMessage}">

<toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastMessageReceived.Header}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
            Foreground="Black"
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" 
            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"/>
            <Rectangle Height="1" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Black" Margin="0,8" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
```

[image: Sample screen with red mark]

Comment: you mean, do you have to stretch the line which is under the red circle as it is under `Deviation 01 Test`?

Comment: I won't add it as an answer because I don't know if it will work, but try to add `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` in the ExpanderView declaration.
Then please let me know if it worked.

Comment: That line which is under Test av Kategorier and Avvik Lager. Now it's as large as header, but I would like to stretch it to screen width like in Deviation 01 Test.

Comment: Adding HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" didn't work. Test av Kategorier and Avvik Lager are still stretch to header width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to get to the bottom of this.  The bottom line is, I think the only way get what you want (stretch the line) is to include a modified version of the [control template](https://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/Themes/Generic.xaml) in your XAML resources, and make the header stretch to fill its container.

If you check source code at the link, and scroll down to the `ExpanderView` control template, you will see that the header element is defined like this:

```
<ListBoxItem x:Name="ExpandableContent" controls:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                                     Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="41"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentControl x:Name="Header"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="Expander"                                            
                        Margin="11,0,0,0"
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Expander}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ExpanderTemplate}"/>
        <Grid x:Name="ExpanderPanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
              Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Transparent"/>
    </Grid>
</ListBoxItem>
```

Now, at first glance this looks fine, because the "Header" ContentControl has both `HorizontalAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` set to "Stretch".  Unfortunately, the parent `ListBoxItem` does not define *its* `HorizontalContentAlignment`, whose default may not be "Stretch".  (I'm uncertain on this point because the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=vs.105).aspx) does not list the default -- but the default for the corresponding property is ["Left" in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) and ["Center" in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=vs.95).aspx).)

So I would try copying the default control template into your application resources, and add the appropriate alignments to the "ExpandableContent" ListBoxItem:

```
<ListBoxItem x:Name="ExpandableContent" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ...
```

Comment: I get copy of repository with Silverlight Toolkit, then changed the source definition and it's just working good. My +1.